# The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Object?>?'., when i can the code got this error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

[image: code is here]

```
return FutureBuilder(
    future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),  The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null.  Try adding a null check ('!').
    ...
```

This is the code where I got the error, I tried to add null check operator but could not work

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the relevant line of code from your screenshot as text.  Q: Did you try `future!: ...`?

Comment: I also add null check but did not work, when i add ! got The method 'call' isn't defined for the class 'User' error

Comment: yes , i Tried future!: , but its an error

Comment: OK: you have several problems.  1) `FirebaseAuto.instance.currentUser()` returns a nullable.  Hence the error. 2) But even if you add `!` ... currentUser() *ISN'T* a future, so it *CAN'T* be used as the "future:" parameter: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` is not a future function. It returns `User?`. Hence, it can't be used as a `future` inside `FutureBuilder`.

Here's a snippet from its source code:

[image]

In your code snippet, I can't figure out why you need this future builder. If you can, remove it completely since you are not using any of its properties. You can return the `ListView.builder` that you are using at line number 32 from line number 23.

I hope that helps!

Comment: but, what if i needed to access current user?

Comment: You can declare a variable `User? currentUser`. And then set its value in `initState` using 

`currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();`

Answer (score 1):

First make variable like this

```
late<User?> Future  user;
```

Then in side initState function do

```
 @override
 initState(){
 
  super.initState();

   user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

}
```

then passed inside futureBuilder

like this

```
FutureBuilder<User?>(
        future:  user,
        builder: (context,child , snapShot){ 
              if(snapShot.data != null)
                {
                    return YOUR_WIDGET ();
                }
              else
                {
                    return ANY LOADING WIDGET():
                }

                                        });
```

note don't forget to but Data Type for futureBuilder like

```
futureBuilder<YOUR DATA TYPE>(...)
```

this for Future in general but you did'nt have to use future builder
instate use normal Widget  but first get user inside initState

```
late user;

@override
 initState(){
 
  super.initState();

   user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(user != null){
    return YOUR_WIDGET

} else {

  return ANY LOADING WIDGET():

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` is a getter not a future.

#### How to go about it ?

Use variable of Type `User?` and then once it is `not null` show the `ListView`

```
User? user;
  @override
  void initState() {
    
    super.initState();
    setState((){
      user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    }
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: user ? <ListView here> : <CircularProgressIndicator here>
    );
  }
```